# How to auto update my application which is developed in c#?

Tags: c#

I have developed my application in c# which uses SQL Server Express as a database. I want to update my application through internet. What I want is to update only myapplication.exe
Because in the installed folder there is also application.config where configuration of that server is included such as Server name, Instance name. I do not want to touch this file. It is unique for every machine. Is there any ready mechanism or codes to do that? Please show me directions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the Microsoft solution `ClickOnce` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.110).aspx

On the open source side, there is `Omaha`, from Google, powering Google Chrome, Google Earth etc. http://code.google.com/p/omaha/

Also, take a look at `Shimmer`, by the folks at Gihub https://github.com/github/Shimmer

Comment: Thanks for direction you have given me, I will check and let you know soon.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need ClickOnce installation.

http://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/archive/2008/01/29/how-to-use-clickonce-to-deploy-your-applications.aspx